# Reverse an array between given indexes

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been asked an interview question to reverse an array. I used the following method and it worked as expected:

```
def reverse(array, i, j):
  if i > j: # ensure i <= j
    i, j = j, i
  while i < j:
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    i += 1
    j -= 1
```

Now, the interviewer asked me to replace the above while loop by for and I was really confused. Please can someone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: but, why? `array[i:j] = array[j:i:-1]`

Comment: Or, `array[i:j] = array[i:j][::-1]`

Comment: Trick counter-question: what's an _array_ in Python, anyway? A list? `array.array`? `numpy.array`?

Comment: @DeepSpace: Careful, it needs to be `array[i:j] = array[j-1:i-1:-1]`.  For `a = list(range(10))`, `a[4:8] = a[8:4:-1]` gives you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 8, 9]`!

Comment: Why are so many people agreeing on the wrong answer

Comment: @TimPietzcker I just tried your example and it gives me `[8,7,6,5]`. What gives? Maybe I missed your point?

Comment: @xyres: Did you look at `a` after the operation? What you're quoting is just the slice `a[8:4:-1]`, not the result of the replace operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forget the `for` loop entirely and do something like this:

```
def reverse(array, i, j):
    # Make sure i is less than j
    if i > j:
        i, j = j, i
    # Reverse array[i:j+1]
    section = array[i:j+1]
    section.reverse()
    array[i:j+1] = section
```

(The `j+1` is to keep consistent with your function's behaviour; both `i` and `j` are treated as inclusive, but Python wants [inclusive, exclusive).)

Or if you want to keep the `for` loop in and avoid standard functions, then you could do something like this:

```
def reverse(array, i, j):
    # Make sure i is less than j
    if i > j:
        i, j = j, i
    # Reverse array[i:j]
    count = j - i + 1
    for offset in range(0, count // 2):
        first = i + offset
        second = j - offset
        array[first], array[second] = array[second], array[first]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a for, but you can also do this:

If you follow the python logic where [i:j] means i <= x < j then you can do this:

```
array[i:j] = array[j-1:i-1:-1]
```

Other way, if you want to get the elements where i <= x <= j then you can do as @darksky suggested:

```
array[i:j+1] = array[j: i - 1: -1]
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. This reverses the sub array with indices [i, j - 1], not [i, j]. It should be `a[i:j+1] = a[j: i - 1: -1]`.

Comment: @darksky Well, that depends if you considered the j index to be inclusive or exclusive. My solution works when it's exclusive as it's in the python. If you want it to be inclusive then yes, your solution is correct. I will expand my answer.

Comment: Sure. That's fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here perform this in a really smart way, but a `for` loop should look something like:

```
for x in range(j - i):
    array[i+x], array[j-x] = array[j-x], array[i+x]
```

Comment: Does not give desired result

Comment: @deep it works for me, provided that `i < j`  Plus, it's the only answer that provides you with a `for` loop which is what you asked for.  Using the implementation exactly as above, but returning `array` gives: `rev([1,2,3,4,5], 1, 3)` `[1,4,3,2,5]`  which is as expected.

Comment: @Baldrickk Thanks. But if `i == j`, shouldn't there be no reversal at all to be done?

Comment: @SamChats correct - I was instead inferring that if `j < i` (two valid indicies, but largest first), it will do no work - not that that is a problem with your loop, I would expect a function written using it to check and swap the values as part of the initial parameter checks.

Comment: @Baldrickk Yes, but the OP has already done that in his function.

Comment: @SamChats yes.  But as it isn't explicitly in your answer (and it doesn't need to be), I was just clarifying that your code snippet also needed that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think more readable example would be:

```
arr[i,j] = reversed(arr[i, j])
```